# Create new list from nested list and convert str into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Apologies for asking a question that have been asked a hundred times before, I'm new to Python and none of the solutions I've found seems to solve my problem.

I have a nested list from a csv file called diabetes, I read in the file and comma separate the elements like this

```
for line in open("diabetes.csv"):
    lst=line.strip().split(",")
    print(lst)
```

which prints out the following

```
['10', '101', '86', '37', '0', '45.6', '1.136', '38', '1']
['2', '108', '62', '32', '56', '25.2', '0.128', '21', '0']
['3', '122', '78', '0', '0', '23', '0.254', '40', '0']
```

Now my problem is

1. I need to make a separate list containing only the third element of each list (lst[2])
2. I need to convert it into floats instead of strings.

I'm using Python 3.6 and I'm pulling my hair out here.

Comment: Use a CSV reader like `pandas` or the standard library `csv` module. Try to avoid reinventing-the-wheel.

Comment: you can declare an array outside `col3 = []` and `col3.append(float(lst[2]))` to it in every loop. Although I agree using the standard `csv` module may be better, a custom implementation does provide more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a list of lists of strings:

```
LoL=[
   ['10', '101', '86', '37', '0', '45.6', '1.136', '38', '1'],
   ['2', '108', '62', '32', '56', '25.2', '0.128', '21', '0'],
   ['3', '122', '78', '0', '0', '23', '0.254', '40', '0'],
]
```

You can get the `nth` element of each sublist like so:

```
>>> [float(sl[2]) for sl in LoL]
[86.0, 62.0, 78.0]
```

If you have a csv file, use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to do exactly the same thing:

(at the command prompt):

```
$ cat file.csv
10,101,86,37,0,45.6,1.136,38,1
2,108,62,32,56,25.2,0.128,21,0
3,122,78,0,0,23,0.254,40,0
```

Python:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as f:
  items=[float(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(f)]

>>> items
[86.0, 62.0, 78.0]
```

So -- bottom line:

1. Please use `csv` or `pandas` instead of `.split(',')` so that you can properly handle quoted csv and other particularities;
2. Use a `with` context manager so the file is automatically closed at the end of the block;
3. A `csv` file is very similar to a list of lists and can usually be handled the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` module, which is pretty standard in data science:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv", header=None, index_col=None)
df.iloc[:, 2] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 2], downcast='float')
list = df.iloc[:, 2]
```

**EDIT**
Note, that the output type in here will be `Series`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and naive one liner:

```
result = [float(line.strip().split(",")[2]) for line in open("diabetes.csv")]
```

Comment: Naive is the key word. Interpreting CSV data via `split` is a bad practice. Use the `csv` library.

Comment: No arguing there. Naive approaches can be very useful when learning though, it's good to not be buried in a pile of libraries when all you want to understand is a for loop.

Comment: True. It's also helpful to teach a pattern that works in the general case so once learned it works forever. I think the "batteries included" lesson is especially important for Python.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you can do:

```
my_list = []

with open("diabetes.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:

    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        lst = line.split(',')
        my_list.append(float(lst[2]))
```

Comment: Your approach is naive and dangerous. Use the`csv` library. Interpreting the CSV lines and fields by yourself in this simplistic way will not deal with quotes and other subtleties of CSV syntax.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Is this better ?